# How to show data with combining of 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `purchase_details_master` and another is `sales_detais_master` Where all the purchase and sales details are available.

**Structure of Purchase Table: These are the data which I have purchased**

[image: Purchase Table]

**Structure of Sales Table: These are the data which I have sell**

[image: Sales Table]

Now I need to show the data like this, This image is showing the **iPhone 12** data. In the `Inward` field showing tha pieces of purchased item, In the `Outward` field showing the data of sells pieces, and the closing data showing like `Opening + Inward` or `Opening - Outward` `= Closing`

[image: Need to show data like this]

I am using Core Php with Sqlite database

```
$item = $_POST['item'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM purchase_details_master WHERE item_id = '$item'";
$sql_run = $conn->query($sql);
```

I have used while loop it's not solving the problem
Kindly solve this out for me! Thank you in Advance

Comment: How the data blongs together?

Comment: The third image is showing from another software which i want in my application, The database structure is same in both application

Comment: Find yourself a beginner tutorial that explains how to use JOINs.

Comment: I have tried join but the preview that I want isn't delivering

Answer (score 0):

A `JOIN` clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

like that.

`SELECT * FROM purchase_details_master AS pdm INNER JOIN sales_detais_master AS sdm ON sdm.item_id = pdm.item_id WHERE sdm.item_id = ?`

Comment: Thank you, But I don't need the INNER JOIN I just wanted to show the data like 3rd Image

Answer (score 0):

this will select all fields from the two tables

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM purchase_details_master, sales_detais_master  WHERE purchase_details_master.item_id = '$item' AND purchase_details_master.item_id = sales_details_master.item_id";
```

or select exact fields from the two tables

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field1, table2.field3 
FROM table1, table2, 
WHERE  table1.field1 = something, or table1.field1 = table2.field2
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please write the code for looping the data like in third image